# Delete image if screen is 3.5"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I'm using auto layout to create my app in iOS 8.1. Everything works fine, except for one thing. My layout has an image that leaves enough space below for other elements on screens that are at least 4". How can I tell Xcode that if the screen is only 3.5" (an iPhone 4S) then the image should be removed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 #define IS_IPHONE4S (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-480)?NO:YES)

if (IS_IPHONE4S){
  [yourImage removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: But, will this make the other elements move to the top of the screen? Because if it just removes the image but the elements are not rearranged it doesn't help :(

Comment: You must delete the affected constraints and include new programmatically according to your need. Hard to say without looking anything. Some docs: https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/ios-how-to-programmatically-add-auto-layout-constraints-for-a-view-that-will-fit-its-superview/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html

Comment: I think this can help you too, look at 19:24  http://youtu.be/4sks5NPz-34?t=19m24s